# How to point subdomain (Site A) to folder (Site B)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos, virtualhost

I need to point http://subdomain.domain-one.com to http://domain-two.com/folder

DomainTwo is running an Apache on CentOS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use iframe. Or ajax load. Depends on your need.

Comment: I need my URL to be http://subdomain.domain-one.com/ but the website is hosted on http://domain-two.com/folder